# What do I use to cover an insulation wrapped duct? (Silver foil wrap?)

Tags: heating, garage, ducts

[image: garage]

I was looking for silver foil to cover the heating duct insulation wrap. What is it called?

Comment: Are you talking about the insulation over your heating duct lines?

Comment: Covering up that duct work with only foil tape is going to be very expensive.

Comment: Doresoom: how expensive? I am good till 100. :-)

Comment: If you want to measure out your area to be covered, it's approximately [$25 for 5400 sq inches](http://www.amazon.com/Nashua-617020-322-3-Foil-Yards-Aluminum/dp/B001S94T1S), which comes out to $0.66/sq. ft. if I did my math right. Don't forget to account for overlap!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for Duct Wrap.  It's actually an insulation in it's own right, being one side foil, and the other side fiber insulation.   I see no reason why you couldn't apply it over top of the existing insulation, provided everything is dry.

[image]

http://www.homedepot.ca/product/reflectix-duct-wrap-12x25/902353

Answer (score 2):

HVAC foil tape or Aluminum foil tape.  What you **DON'T** want is a fabric/cloth duct tape.